# SGA/PGA Memory @ oracle-xe 11g - увеличить

Tags: ubuntu, oracle, memory

Добрый день

У меня на VPS сервере (Ubuntu 14) развернута БД Oracle-XE 11g.

Столкнулся с тем, что БД работает тише, чем хотелось бы. Хочу увеличить количество выделенной под БД памяти, но не получается. В apex memory отсутствует (логинюсь под admin), если бы был интерфейс доступен, то более менее понятно описано тут: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/memory.htm.

В общем, буду очень рад, если поможете увеличить память, выделенную под Оракл. Возможно, есть ограничение 1Г для XE.

```
root@s05657de2:~#free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          6.0G       732M       5.3G       327M         0B       596M
-/+ buffers/cache:       136M       5.9G
Swap:         2.0G         0B       2.0G


root@s05657de2:~# df -h
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop11458p1   40G  3.8G   35G  11% /
none               3.0G  4.0K  3.0G   1% /dev
none               4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none               615M   44K  615M   1% /run
none               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none               3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /run/shm
none               100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
shmfs              4.0G  259M  3.8G   7% /dev/shm
```

Comment: Настройки памяти - глобальные параметры. меняютя в конфигах и требуют перезапуска севера. не забывайте бекапить (init/spfile), а то можно не запустится после изменения. https://community.oracle.com/thread/945562?tstart=0

Comment: Вы про /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/spfileXE.ora ?                        Я так понял поменять нужно эти строки:                                                              XE.__java_pool_size=4194304
XE.__large_pool_size=4194304
XE.__oracle_base='/u01/app/oracle'#ORACLE_BASE set from environment
XE.__pga_aggregate_target=289406976
XE.__sga_target=247463936
XE.__shared_io_pool_size=25165824
XE.__shared_pool_size=155189248
XE.__streams_pool_size=0

Answer (score 2):

В версии 11.01 задача была упрощена, был введён [AMM (*Automatic Memory Management*)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/memory003.htm#ADMIN11011).

Теперь возможно одним параметром `memory_target` увеличить объём выделенной памяти для SGA/PGA (`sga_target` и `pga_aggregate_target` при этом должны быть установлены на 0).

Допустим, желаемый макс. объём выделенной памяти 2G:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  820236288 bytes
[...]
SQL> alter system set memory_target=2g scope=spfile;
SQL> alter system set sga_target=0 scope=spfile;
SQL> alter system set pga_aggregate_target=0 scope=spfile;
SQL>
SQL> shutdown
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup 
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2042241024 bytes
[...]
```